# How can I package a windows dependent program into a lightweight docker container?

Tags: docker, devops, windows-container, nano-server, server-core

I currently have a folder containing some .dll files, .bin files and some .exe files. The main .exe that I will be executing only works on windows, and I am not entirely sure what are all its dependencies. My goal is to package all the files in the folder into a docker container so I can integrate it into the rest of my pipeline. The main .exe is a command line tool which is only called once with some arguments and left to run.

I have tried to use windows server core as the container image and it works. However this image is too big for my needs. I have tried to use nano server but when I try to run the executable there is nothing printed in the command line and the program does not run. In that scenario, if I type:

`C:\Bin\x64>echo %ERRORLEVEL%`

I get the following output:

`-1073741515`

Meaning I am missing some dependencies.

So, I'm wondering if there is an alternate solution to packaging this folder since windows server core is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'll have to stick with the Server Core image. The main thing is that these images server different purposes, and the Nano Server is intended to new applications being developed with the targeted Nano Server API. Server Core is the image focused on existing apps, but its APIs make the image larger than what one would expect from a container.

Keep in mind that it's still better than a full VM. :)

I blogged about this here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/nano-server-x-server-core-x-server-which-base-image-is-the-right/ba-p/2835785